# ? , & problems in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am creating a XML file from a database using PHP..

I am following a syntax something like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY field1";

$resultID = mysql_query($query, $linkID) or die("Data not found.");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID);

$xml_output .="\t\t\t\t\t\t<given_name>"  . $row['fieldname'] . "</given_name>\n";

echo $xml_output
```

everything works well and almost a well formed XML is formed..
But there is a problem with some of the characters like &, ? etc.,
How can i overcome this??
I dont want to string replace these..

I want my XML to be off a special structure which needs to be validated against a specified schema..

Help appreciated..

Comment: And what problem is it exactly?

Comment: Error something like this : Value 'Morre?' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[\x00-/:->@-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-\v10ffff]*[\x00-\x08\x0b-\f\x0e-\x1f!-/:->@-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-\v10ffff][\x00-\x08\x0b-\f\x0e-\x1f!-/:->@-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-\v10ffff]*[\x00-/:->@-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-??-\v10ffff]*'.
[Error] XML.xml:5747:32: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Morre?' of element 'surname' is not valid.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build XML documents by mashing together strings. Don't do that. Use an XML library.

Comment: And some other error like XML not well formed because of '&'

Comment: You should use [`DOMDocument`](http://ca2.php.net/DOMDocument) to create the XML instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a PHP class like DOMDocument to create your XML rather than do it manually. In any case you should escape these characters if you're double quoting strings. EDIT: as already suggested by @Francois Deschenes

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem with the “?” char? I don’t think it has any special meaning in XML…

Comment: But i want my XML to be off a structure..it needs to be validated against a specified schema..

Comment: @Don: So? What do you want to tell us with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions come up immediatly :

1. Use `<[[CDATA` sections. No need in that case to escape special chars.
2. Escape those chars. `&` is equals to `&amp;`. htmlspecialchars is indeed a PHP function to transform your data. But I'd rather go with the first solution.

Comment: What if the data contains `]]>`?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to encode your special characters.

Comment: `htmlentities` will produce HTML entities. Most of them do not validate against most XML DTDs/Schemas (unless these define said entities). I think what you want here is `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: You’re right, my bad. I think someone posted an answer with `htmlentities`, thus provoking my reply. I then reloaded the page to see if anything new happened and I pasted without thinking.